# Assigning values to dynamic array

Tags: solidity, arrays

I am trying to assign values to an Array, but it is giving me an error

**from solidity:
TypeError: Type uint8[5] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[] memory.
--> Web3/Array.sol:31:15:
|
31 |         val = [1,2,3,4,5];**

```
function example() public{
    uint[] memory val = new uint[](5);
    val = [1,2,3,4,5];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you were trying to do was assign a fixed size memory array `[1,2,3,4,5]` to a dynamically-sized memory array `val`. This is not allowed. If you want to initialize dynamically-sized arrays, you have to assign the individual elements:

```
 function example() public{
    uint[] memory val = new uint[](5);
    val[0] = 1;
    val[1] = 2;
    val[2] = 3;
    val[3] = 4;
    val[4] = 5;
}
```

See: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays